# Activerecord proper associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have four models

`Bid` `Order` `User` `Printer`

currently I cannot access the order through anything except `User`.

I would like to be able to do something of the sort `bid.order` but have yet to figure out the correct association.  Any thoughts?

```
class Bid < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :printer
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :bids
end

class Printer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders, through: :bids
  has_many :bids
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders
end
```

Comment: in class `Bid` you need `has_one :order`

Comment: It will be `Bid` `belongs_to :order`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both models must know about the relationship so you need to state that in the Bid model

```
class Bid < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :printer
  belongs_to :order
end
```